# How to get last five minutes logs in C# console .exe file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to get last 5 minutes logs for use to this below code. this code is given to all logs that created I only want to last 5 minute logs. how can I get anyone can please help me...

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            WriteLogs.WriteLog("ConsoleLog", String.Format("{0} @ {1}", "Log is Created at", DateTime.Now));
            Console.WriteLine("Log is Written Successfully !!!");
            Console.ReadLine();
         } 
    }

 class WriteLogs
    {
        public static bool WriteLog(string strFileName, string strMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream objFilestream = new FileStream(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", Path.GetTempPath(), strFileName), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                StreamWriter objStreamWriter = new StreamWriter((Stream)objFilestream);
                objStreamWriter.WriteLine(strMessage);
                objStreamWriter.Close();
                objFilestream.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Read the log file line by line, parse each line to extract the date, compare the date time with the current one

Comment: You're writing to a file, not using a log. You'll have to write everything yourself - if you want to read the last 5 minutes of data, you'll have to open the file using a different stream, parse the lines and extract the data. If you want to create separate logs every 5 minutes, or keep only 5 minutes of logs, you'll have to write it yourself

Comment: On the other hand, if you use a logging library like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/), [time-based file management](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file) (eg rolling log files, max time per file etc) is built into the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are appending to the same log file with same string format, you can just read the file line by line or all lines at once. But since you need last 5 minutes logs, those logs would always be near the end of the file. So lets just use the later approach (We can also read a file line by line in reverse, but its tricky and would require lot of code and considerations).

First you need to define a function which fetches the logs from a given date as below -

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetLogs(string strFileName, DateTime dateTime)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), strFileName);
    var logs = File.ReadAllLines(path).Where(w =>
               {
                 var date = DateTime.Parse(w.Split("@")[1]);
                 return date >= dateTime;
               });
    return logs;
}
```

Call the above function as below to get last 5 minutes logs -

```
var logs = GetLogs("ConsoleLog", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5));
```

Comment: I want affected row count also how can I get? @Nikhil Patil

Comment: @ShefaliChaudhari, You mean count of logs for last 5 minutes? You can get it by calling logs.Count()

Comment: Thank you @Nikhil Patil